# The parameter type `T` may not live long enough when writing a binary searching tree

Tags: reference, rust, binary-search-tree, lifetime-scoping

I'm trying to write a binary searching tree in Rust, but I don't understand what is going on:

```
enum BST<'a, T: Ord> {
    Leaf,
    BinTree { value: T, left: &'a mut BST<'a, T>, right: &'a mut BST<'a, T> }
}

impl<'a, T: Ord> BST<'a, T> {
    fn new() -> BST<'a, T> {
        BST::Leaf
    }

    fn add(self, val: T) {
        match self {
            BST::Leaf => self = BST::BinTree {
                value: val,
                left: &mut BST::<'a, T>::new(),
                right: &mut BST::<'a, T>::new()
            },
            BST::BinTree{value: v, left: l, right: r} => if val < v {
                l.add(val);
            } else {
                r.add(val);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following errors:

```
error[E0309]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
 --> heap.rs:3:25
  |
3 |     BinTree { value: T, left: &'a mut BST<'a, T>, right: &'a mut BST<'a, T> }
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'a`...
note: ...so that the reference type `&'a mut BST<'a, T>` does not outlive the data it points at
 --> heap.rs:3:25
  |
3 |     BinTree { value: T, left: &'a mut BST<'a, T>, right: &'a mut BST<'a, T> }
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Well, after doing lots of research and doing the things that the compiler suggests I came up with this code:

```
enum BST<'a, T: Ord + 'a> {
    Leaf,
    BinTree { 
        value: T,
        left: &'a mut BST<'a, T>,
        right: &'a mut BST<'a, T>
    }
}

impl<'a, T: Ord + 'a > BST<'a, T> {
    fn new() -> BST<'a, T> {
        BST::Leaf
    }

    fn add(&mut self, val: T) {
        match *self {
            BST::Leaf => *self = BST::BinTree {
                value: val,
                left: &mut BST::<'a, T>::new() as &'a mut BST<'a, T>,
                right: &mut BST::<'a, T>::new() as &'a mut BST<'a, T>
            },
            BST::BinTree{value: ref v, left: ref mut l, right: ref mut r} => if val < *v {
                l.add(val);
            } else {
                r.add(val);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
}
```

But I still get errors:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> heap.rs:19:16
   |
19 |                left: &mut BST::<'a, T>::new() as &'a mut BST<'a, T>,
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
20 |                right: &mut BST::<'a, T>::new() as &'a mut BST<'a, T>
21 |            },
   |            - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at 15:27...
  --> heap.rs:15:28
   |
15 |    fn add(&mut self, val: T) {
   |  ____________________________^
16 | |      match *self {
17 | |          BST::Leaf => *self = BST::BinTree {
18 | |              value: val,
...  |
27 | |      }
28 | |  }
   | |__^

error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> heap.rs:20:17
   |
20 |                right: &mut BST::<'a, T>::new() as &'a mut BST<'a, T>
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
21 |            },
   |            - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at 15:27...
  --> heap.rs:15:28
   |
15 |    fn add(&mut self, val: T) {
   |  ____________________________^
16 | |      match *self {
17 | |          BST::Leaf => *self = BST::BinTree {
18 | |              value: val,
...  |
27 | |      }
28 | |  }
   | |__^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

I know this can be fixed by using `Box`es instead of references, but I want to make it like this for exercise.

Comment: Have you tried placing a bound `+ 'a` on `T` alongside `Ord`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We [expect a good amount of effort here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/155423). For example, have you tried doing **what the compiler suggests**: *consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'a`*? If not, *why not*? If you did, what issue did you have with that? There are also [19 or so existing questions with the same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+The+parameter+type+may+not+live+long+enough+is%3Aq). You should read through them because someone has already taken the time to answer them. Tell us what doesn't work after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, that specific error can be fixed by adding a lifetime bound `T: 'a`. But then you'll get many other errors, because what you are trying to do is unsound: You are trying to store references to objects which don't have an owner elsewhere.

When you do something like storing `&mut BST::<'a, T>::new()` in your node, `BST::<'a, T>::new()` returns a temporary value which will soon be destroyed, so you can't store a reference to it and expect it to live on.

Instead of references, you need your node to own its children. You can do this by changing the child type to `left: Box<BST<T>>` and using `Box::new` when you create a new child node. Once you do this, you can get rid of all the `'a` everywhere and won't get the lifetime-related errors.

Another issue is that your `add` consumes the `self` parameter so it won't be able to be used anymore by the caller. You should make it take `&mut self` instead so that it can modify the tree owned by the caller.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and notifying me for the mistake with `self`. But as I said i'd like to make it with references for exercise.

Comment: @DimoChanev I understand that, but as I explained that would be impossible because the nodes have no owner.