# How to pass a PrimInt to multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, generics, rust

I would like to write a function that accepts an integer, and spawns threads that use this integer. The integer could be computed. It doesn't need to be a literal. If I use a concrete type such as `usize`, it would work but when I try to generalize it, it [fails to compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a68effae1553bf3bfc0dc5ae0030a90):

```rust
fn g<A>(a: A)
where
    A: num::PrimInt + Copy + std::fmt::Debug + Send,
{
    let hs = (0..3).map(|_| {
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("{:?}", a);
        })
    });

    for h in hs {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
1 | fn g<A>(a: A)
  |      - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `A: 'static`...
...
6 |         std::thread::spawn(move || {
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/main.rs:6:28: 8:10 a:A]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
6 |         std::thread::spawn(move || {
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Since I have the `Copy` trait, it should be able to copy this value for each thread and hence the lifetime bound recommendation is not necessary. How do I resolve this?

Comment: This recommendation _is_ necessary. Consider that all immutable references are `Copy`, regardless of their lifetime.

Comment: @Michail What reference? It is an integer and I would like to make a copy of it for every thread.

Comment: True, but a reference type might one day implement `PrimInt`, and the compiler guards agains that.

Comment: @Michail That makes no sense. It is the purpose of Copy to indicate the value can be copied.

Comment: I'm really bad at explaining things, so here's a question with an informative explanation: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972233/why-do-i-need-to-provide-lifetimes-for-a-structs-generic-parameters-which-are-n/49972692#49972692) for a similar situation.

Comment: It would seem absurd if it is not possible to copy a generic integer to multiple threads ...

Comment: I think you have two easy ways to do this. Since `a` is copy, you could re-assign it to a new `let` binding, which (as you point out) would copy it. Otherwise, since `Copy` requires `Clone`, you could explicitly `a.clone()`, which will also create a copy.

Comment: Note that this is expressed in the constraint `F: Send + 'static` on `std::thread::spawn`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html

Comment: Also, `PrimInt` is a trait in the `num`crate and not in the standard library, so the compiler can't assume anything special about it.

Comment: `num::PrimInt` could (should?) add `'static` as a supertrait, then this would work.

Answer (score 1):

`Copy` and `'static` are different constraints, and *both* are necessary for a value to be moved across threads. While you may only intend to pass integers (which satisfy both `Copy` and `'static`) to your generic function, the compiler cannot know for sure. It must be able to prove that the function body is valid for **all** possible type parameters. An example of a type which is `Copy` but not `'static` is a [reference to a local variable](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=70bdf975682ab592ad024661eba958ff):

```rust
fn assert_is_copy<T: Copy>(_: T) {}
fn assert_is_static<T: 'static>(_: T) {}

fn main() {
    let x: usize = 5;

    assert_is_copy(x);
    assert_is_static(x);
    assert_is_copy(&x);
    //assert_is_static(&x); // FAILS TO COMPILE
}
```

I think you'll agree that you don't want to be passing references to *your* stack variables to different threads (although it can be safe in [some limited cases](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.1/crossbeam/thread/struct.Scope.html)). If you did, you could detach that thread, pop the stack frame with the local variable on it, and cause undefined behavior!

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053550/the-compiler-suggests-i-add-a-static-lifetime-because-the-parameter-type-may-no#answer-40053649) gives a simple, (mostly) correct explanation of what it means to say `T: 'static`.

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained *why* your code doesn't work, but if you're still wondering *how* to make it work, simply add `+ 'static` to your constraints:

```
fn g<A>(a: A)
where
    A: num::PrimInt + Copy + std::fmt::Debug + Send + 'static,
{
    let hs = (0..3).map(|_| {
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("{:?}", a);
        })
    });

    for h in hs {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said in my original question, the integer may be computed and is not a literal. `'static` does not work for my use case.

Answer (score -1):

The direct answer to my question based on the other answers is the following:

**In Rust, it is not possible to pass a computed, non-literal `PrimInt` to more than one thread.**

Comment: This is wrong. All primitive integer types (e.g. `u32`, `isize`) are `'static`. It does not matter whether they come from a literal or are computed at runtime.

Comment: All you needed to do to see this was to follow the compiler's recommendation (add a `'static` bound to `A`), then pass any integer value to `g`.